# Find out reason for automatic break

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

Soon after I press the Play button, the Unity break button automatically gets activated: Unity gets into Pause mode:

[image]

I have attached the Unity debugger to my C# code, but Visual Studio doesn't break.

How could I find out the reason why Unity goes into Break mode?

Thank you!

Edit: Per request, here is the button before pressing Play:

[image]

And here is what the console looks like after the error occured:

[image]

Comment: Show me what the button looks like before you press the play button

Comment: Can you search your project to find whether any of your scripts or imported assets/libraries are setting [EditorApplication.isPaused](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-isPaused.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a Debug.Break(); statement in my code.
Even though attached, the VS debugger didn't indicate where it stopped.

I'm not sure if that is bug. I was expecting VS to indicate where it stops if the debugger is attached.

I have asked the bug report team this question, and I will update my answer as soon as I hear back from them.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the console (bottom left). If the "pause on error" option is enabled and you get an error, it will pause the game. Maybe you had it on.

Comment: Thank you, but it wasn't enabled. I have attached a screenshot to my posting.